# Magento StackExchange Role in Magento Developer Career

Tags: discussion, magento

I have few questions related to **Magento StackExchage Platform**.

- **How much important is this platform in a Magento developer career?**
- **Is it must to join to become expert at Magento?**
- **Does it help developer in getting good job in well reputed company?**
- **Do you think a Magento developer can become expert without joining this platform?**

Answers to these questions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

> How much important is this platform in a magento developer career?

For me this platform has been a big help from time to time. Some weird issue I ran into which had a ready to go solution posted here. In general monitoring questions coming by gives you a good idea of what is going on with the platform

> Is it must to join to become expert at magento?

Nope, you can definately become an expert without. It's just another tool or place to learn sstuff.

> Does it help developer in getting good job in well reputed company?

The company I'm with takes reputation online into account since it says something about that person. You still need to be a good developer but if someone has a high rank it means he can at least explain stuff well and solves issues.

> Do you think a magento developer can become expert without joining this platform?

You can, for sure. But this platform helps

Answer (score 7):

> How much important is this platform in a magento developer career?

Not sure about this. For sure it is important in your everyday job if you work with magento intensively. You get a lot of answers and ideas on this website for problems or impediments you may have in your project. So this platform certainly helps.

> Is it must to join to become expert at magento?

No. But it may help along the way.

> Does it help developer in getting good job in well reputed company?

Indirectly, yes, but it's not enough. It helps you build your skills that may help you get a good job.
Directly...maybe. I've seen some job posts that under the section "Nice to have" ask for reputation on the stackexchange network. This won't get you the job but it may get you priority on an interview.

> Do you think a magento developer can become expert without joining this platform?

Yes, it's possible.  I know a few.

Comment: Thanks for sharing detailed answer. Really appreacited

Answer (score 3):

Here is my opinion on your questions.

**How much important is this platform in a Magento developer career?**

I think MageStackExchangeange is the best and very useful platform for Magento developers. This platform is very useful for newbies also very helpful for the experienced developer of Magento to find solutions in a very quick way.

**Is it must join to become expert at Magento?**

No, But if you join MSE. You can learn Magento development very fastly by other answers and also by solving other problems.

**Does it help a developer in getting a good job in the well-reputed company?**

Yes, If you have a good profile in MSE. It definitely helps to get a job in the well-reputed company.

**Do you think a Magento developer can become expert without joining this platform?**

Yes, But as said before if you join MSE then you can learn Magento very quickly by posting your problems and by solving other problems.

Comment: Nice explanation +1 from me!